# Check if a value is less than any value of an array

Tags: ruby

I have a time-stamp `'2016-02-08 16:23:53'` and an array containing different time-stamps `['2016-02-09 14:23:53', '2015-02-08 16:23:53', '2016-02-08 16:22:53']`.

What is the simplest way to check if the value is less than any of the value in array and return `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking if a value is less than any value in an array may be accomplished in Ruby with

```
value < array_of_values.min
```

The **simplest** way to solve the example given by the OP is

```
'2016-02-08 16:23:53' < ['2016-02-09 14:23:53', 
                         '2015-02-08 16:23:53', 
                         '2016-02-08 16:22:53'].min
```

Comparing string representations of dates and times will only work if all strings involved use the same format, the numbers are ordered from big to small (years down to seconds), and the numbers use leading zeros.

The use of adequate data types (like *Time* or *DateTime*) instead of strings for storing and processing dates and times will improve the robustness of the software.

Comment: For not-so-smart-people who do not understand the value of this answer, the hints are: y-m-d-h-m-s order, zero-padding, fixed length, and the ordering of 0-9 in ASCII.

Comment: @sawa This will fail in C century (10000 year :))

Comment: @mudasobwa Hahaha, I would be too deadly to be blamed by then.

Comment: @sawa Thanks for the constructive hints!

Answer (score 6):

If timestamps are strings:

```
['2016-02-09 14:23:53', '2015-02-08 16:23:53', '2016-02-08 16:22:53'].none? do |ts| 
  Time.parse(ts) > Time.parse('2016-02-08 16:23:53')
end
```

If timestamps are already instances of `Time`, there is no need for `parse`:

```
timestamps_array.none? do |ts|
  ts > Time.parse('2016-02-08 16:23:53')
end
```

Well, for the sake of @sawa’s patience :)

It is inefficient to parse the value to compare against each time in the loop:

```
timestamp_to_check = Time.parse('2016-02-08 16:23:53')
['2016-02-09 14:23:53', '2015-02-08 16:23:53', '2016-02-08 16:22:53'].none? do |ts| 
  Time.parse(ts) > timestamp_to_check
end
```

Comment: It is inefficient to parse `'2016-02-08 16:23:53'` each time in the loop. And to be strict, this does not tell if it is less; it tells if it is not greater. You should naturally use `all?`. I don't see a reason you negated it.

Comment: @sawa I know, but the penalty is insignificant.

Comment: What about the last answer: value < array.min

Comment: You can adapt the other answer's solution: `arr.none? { |ts| ts >= '2016-02-08 16:23:53' }` (or `all?` and `<`)

Comment: @Stefan I could, but I won’t. I am still convinced that in real life dates should be compared as dates. The string-only solution is brave and smart, it’s fine for ruby golfs, olympic games etc. But in real world tomorrow I’ll get dates without leading zeroes.

Comment: Fair enough. One minor nitpick: according to the Ruby documentation, you should use `DateTime` when dealing with historical dates (and calendars) and `Time` when dealing with current dates.